# How to receive multiple parameters of different types in chain extension

Tags: ink, smart-contract, chain-extension

As ink chain-extension example https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/examples/rand-extension/runtime/chain-extension-example.rs#L32 .
It show how to receive one param.

But if I want receive multiple param. How to handler it ?

such as

```
#[ink::chain_extension]
pub trait FetchRandom {
    type ErrorCode = RandomReadErr;

    /// Note: this gives the operation a corresponding `func_id` (1101 in this case),
    /// and the chain-side chain extension will get the `func_id` to do further operations.
    #[ink(extension = 1101, returns_result = false)]
    fn fetch_random(subject: [u8; 32], another: Vec<u8> ) -> [u8; 32];
}
```

Can I receive `another` param as above？

Answer (score 3):

All your args will be passed as a SCALE encoded message param.
That's why on the runtime you should decode it using a struct that derive Scale Encode + Decode + MaxEncodedLen and have the exact same types.

In your contract:

```
    // PSP22 transfer
#[ink(extension = 0xdb20f9f5)]
fn transfer(
    asset_id: u32,
    to: <ink_env::DefaultEnvironment as Environment>::AccountId,
    value: <ink_env::DefaultEnvironment as Environment>::Balance,
) -> Result<(), Psp22Error>;
```

In the runtime:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Encode, Decode, MaxEncodedLen)]
pub struct Psp22TransferInput<AssetId, AccountId, Balance> {
    pub asset_id: AssetId,
    pub to: AccountId,
    pub value: Balance,
}

let input: Psp22TransferInput<T::AssetId, T::AccountId, T::Balance> =
                    env.read_as()?;
```

You can check [Parity ink! example](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1244/files) of PSP22 implementation (more basic as it will serve as an example)

And [OpenBrush example](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts/pull/104/files) PSP22 implementation (more advanced as it targets to be production-ready)

Answer (score 3):

Pierre is right, your arguments need to be encodeable/decodeable (`T: Encode + Decode`).
By doing this you'll be able to use the
[`read_as`](https://crates.parity.io/pallet_contracts/chain_extension/struct.Environment.html#method.read_as)
method in your chain extension implementation which will try and correctly decode the
bytes in the memory buffer into the specified Rust types.

You can then do something like this

```rust
let (type_a, type_b): (TypeA, TypeB) = env.read_as()?;
```

I don't believe having the same field names matters, but having the exact same types definitely does.

Also, as another resource take a look at the [Runtime-Contract-Interactions](https://github.com/justinFrevert/Runtime-Contract-Interactions) repository.

Comment: I don't believe having the same field names matters -> exactly, only types are needed for contextual information (edited my message)